# How to achieve 100% test coverage for the below code? --Schedule Apex and it's test class shown below

Tags: scheduled-apex

The schedule Apex code is shown below:

```
global class DailyLeadProcessor implements Schedulable {


    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){
        List<Lead> leadList = [Select id from Lead where LeadSource = null LIMIT 200];
        System.debug('LeadList will null LeadSource:' + leadList);
            List<Lead> emptyList = new List<Lead>();

        if(!leadList.isEmpty()){
            for(Lead l : leadList){
            l.LastName = 'SchedulableList';
            l.Company = 'YourSongs';
            l.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
            l.Status='Working - Not Contacted';
            emptyList.add(l);
         }
        update emptyList;
        }
    }
 }
```

[image]

Looks everything fine but don't know the exact reason why it is not covering 100% test coverage. I tried other way around too to make it 100% but all went in vain and finally have to ask in stackexchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your execute query you are looking for records where Leadsource is null but you are populating it in the test data.

Please make sure to create the test data in the test class according to the query in the Scheduler I.e marking Leadsource as `null` or blank.

Also, in the test class, I would suggest to put the asserts after the `Test.stoptest` statement.

Comment: @Manit5190. I never realized that.It really helped me..I was working on this issue since 4 hrs just to figure it out.

Comment: But you know the expected output size/count is 0 instead of 200. assertEquals function is failing to validate when I am asserting after the Test.stopTest().

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. You should query and assert after the Test.stoptest method. It ensures all async tasks are completed i.e the scheduler run is complete.

Comment: Isn't it wrong if the size is 0 instead of 200,though the test coverage is 100%?

Comment: No, it not wrong. The assert is being called before the Scheduler finishes, remember scheduler is async. I suggest to have a look at the how to test async apex. And my previous comment.